# Unicode fonts in php page in web browser showing as ? marks, how can i correct it?

Tags: php, html, unicode

Im developing a website with some indian unicode characters, I have xampp installed on my pc and when I test on my local server, unicode characters are showing fine, but when i upload it to web server all the unicode characters are showing like ?? marks....

My web server is Linux based, So Can anybody help....

This is from my website:

> [image]

This is from my local web server:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that your server uses UTF8 as default-charset(maybe you'll need to modify the server-settings).

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Put the line above to your httpd.conf(if possible...then restart the server) or to a `.htaccess`-file on the top-level of the DOCUMENT_ROOT(no restart needed)

Declaring the charset via the meta-tag will not be sufficient, it will be overridden by the charset-header(if any exists) sent by the server.

You also can send the header from within your scripts:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Comment: how and where do i add this command u specified... can you explain please

Comment: but why i can see the unicode letters in my local servers and not on the web server...

Comment: because your local server may use another default-charset. See edits in my post to see where to put the line.

Comment: The `AddDefaultCharset`, httpd.conf and `.htaccess` are specific to the Apache HTTP server (and its derivatives), which it sorta sounds like the OP might be using. PHP's `header()` ought to work in general.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare your charset as utf-8 in your html, like in this example from [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meta):

```
<!-- Defining the charset in HTML4 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- In HTML5 -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: yes i have added and i can see the unicode characters in my local xampp server, but on the web server i cannot see...

Comment: This won't help if the HTTP server is sending a Content-Type header indicating a different character set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the character set is UTF-8 in your HTTP headers, the way to do that depends on your server: http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

If you don't feel like configuring your web server you can also use a `<meta http-equiv>` tag in the `<head>` of your web page, which can be equivalent to an HTTP header.